# NHibernate validator or Fluent Validation?

Tags: nhibernate, validation, domain-driven-design

I use NHibernate. I need to decide how validate domain entities. What do you recommend? Are there any troubles if use NHibernate with Fluent Validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluent validation is really good for user input validation, and can be used for simple business rules. But it has no integration with NHibernate. That means that nothing would prevent NHibernate from saving not valid entity except your custom code.

On other hand there is a NHibernate validator project. It has an integration with nhibernate, and it won't let you to save not valid entity.

Answer (score 3):

Of the O/RM tools I know, NHibernate has the smallest footprint in the C# code of domain classes. It *almost* allows working with POCO's while being totally oblivious of dependencies. That is exactly what FluentValidation allows too. So it seems like a happy marriage to me.

But I wouldn't dare recommend or advise against any validation tool or framework without knowing more of your context. There are many candidates and they would work with NHibernate as well. Data access and validation are two different concerns that should (and can) be separated from one another.

Answer (score 1):

Generally your domain shouldn't know about your ORM. It should be kept in isolation. So my answer is:
 I Can not see any issue with NH and FNH Validation, but keep domain in isolation as much as possible.